# Stringified object stored but not being displayed

Tags: reactjs

```
}, () => { 
      this.addTotals();
           const unified = Object.assign({}, {cart: 
           this.state.cart}, {subTotal: this.state.cartSubTotal})
           localStorage.setItem('myObject', 
           JSON.stringify(unified))
      });
};
```

I have this callback function (project is a little store to buy stuff just for testing) in the code above where I stringify a merged object to later save it in the local storage.
Now the problem is that it does not work, meaning although the data is being displayed in the local storage when I use developer tools, when I refresh, the items (product and subtotal) are not displayed in the cart component. This is my componentDidMount where I'm not sure if the mistake is in here:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.setProducts();
    this.setState({unified : !localStorage.getItem('myObject') 
           ? {}
           : JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myObject'))
    })

};
```

Comment: A possible race condition maybe? What does `this.setProducts();` do? localStorage is usually pretty straightforward. What happens if you grab it in `componentDidMount() { const test = localStorage.getItem('myObject'); console.log(test)`?

Comment: I get a "cart" object with an array in it which then contains an object with the product information and a string? -> "subTotal":0. 
subTotal is the thing I want besides the product infos in the cart object. But it is always zero  although I have stuff in the cart.
And when I refresh the products are gone but the cart object is still there